# Append node to Parent based on user TextField and JComboBox input

Tags: java, algorithm, swing, jpanel

I'm building a Tree traversal program which allows users to run BFS and DFS traversals, as well as add and remove nodes.

What I'm stuck on is getting the node from the JComboBox and passing it to `appendNode()`. I want to achieve this:

[image]

First, I add and connect a bunch of nodes... `addNode()` adds nodes to the `nodeList`.

Then I add all the nodes to JComboBox `parents`:

```
for (Nodes n : nodeList) {
    parents.addItem(n.getValue());
}
```

As you can see above, the nodes are successfully added to the JComboBox.

Then I create a new class:

```
//send in selected parent from combo box
     AppendChildren ac = new AppendChildren(child, parents);
     this.child.addActionListener(ac);
     this.AddButton.addActionListener(ac);
```

Which makes use of this class...

```
class AppendChildren implements ActionListener {

  private TextField child;
  private JComboBox parents;
  private int index;


  public AppendChildren(TextField child, JComboBox parent, int parentIndex) {
    this.child = child;
    this.parents = parent;
    this.index = parentIndex;
  }

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
      //set max input to 2 characters   
      if (child.getText().length() <= 0) {
          addMoreMessage = "Please name your child...";
      }
      else {
          addMoreMessage = "";
      }
      if (child.getText().length()>1) {
          child.setText(child.getText().substring(0,1));
      }
      String childName = child.getText();
      parents.setSelectedIndex(index);
      Nodes newChild = new Nodes(childName, nodeX, nodeY, nodeWidth, nodeHeight);

      appendNode(parentNode, newChild);
  }
}
```

Which calls `appendNode(Nodes parent, Nodes child) {` to connect the nodes and recreate the adjacency matrix.

**My question is:** How can I get the Node selected from the JComboBox and pass it into `appendNode()`? I'm able to get the string value from the TextField just fine...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `nodeList` is an `ArrayList`, try putting the following before the call of `appendNode()`:

```
Nodes parentNode = nodeList.get(parents.getSelectedIndex());
```

Since you've added the nodes to the combo box in the same order that they appear in `nodeList` making them essentially mirrored, the above line should work.